# Manipulating a PNG image in C leading to either memory leaks or white stripes on image

Tags: c, image-processing, memory-leaks, png

We are supposed to make a program that manipulates a PNG picture. One of the options is to enlarge the image, to double its size. We have got some functions from our teachers for reading and saving the image to and from files.

```
// This function reads an image from the filename source. Will store
// the image in the Pixel 2dim array and allocate the needed space.
void readImage(char *filename, Image *img);

// This function actually writes out the PNG image file. The string 'title' is
// also written into the image file
void writeImage(char* filename, Image *img);
```

This is a school project but I am really new to programming and I have been staring myself blind on this code for weeks now without any real progress and would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

These are two structs we are working with, which were given by the teachers.

```
typedef struct pixel
{
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
} Pixel;

typedef struct image
{
    Pixel **pixels;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int width;
} Image;
```

One version of the code, where the enlargement function works, but gives memory leaks.

```
void imageEnlarge(Image *pic)
{

    temp.height = plain.height;
    temp.width = plain.width;

    temp.pixels = (Pixel**)malloc(sizeof(Pixel*) * temp.height);
    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < plain.height; h++)
    {
        temp.pixels[h] = (Pixel*)malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * temp.width);
        for (unsigned int w = 0; w < plain.width; w++)
        {
            temp.pixels[h][w] = plain.pixels[h][w];
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < plain.width; h++)
    {
        free(plain.pixels[h]);
    }
    free(plain.pixels);

    plain.height = temp.height * 2;
    plain.width = temp.width * 2;

    plain.pixels = (Pixel**)malloc(sizeof(Pixel*) * plain.height);
    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < plain.height; h++)

   {
        plain.pixels[h] = (Pixel*)malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * plain.width);
        for (unsigned int w = 0; w < plain.width; w++)
        {
            plain.pixels[h][w] = tempP.pixels[h * tempP.height / plain.height][w * tempP.width / plain.width];
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < temp.width; h++)
    {
        free(temp.pixels[h]);
    }
    free(temp.pixels);
}
```

Another version where the enlargement results in a larger image but every two pixels are white throughout the entire image, as if the pixels have had its sized doubled but doesn't entirely fill the pixel. No memory leaks!

```
void imageEnlarge(Image *pic)
{
    temp.height = plain.height * 2;
    temp.width = plain.width * 2;

    temp.pixels = (Pixel**)malloc(sizeof(Pixel*) * temp.height);
    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < temp.height; h++)
    {
        temp.pixels[h] = (Pixel*)malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * temp.width);
}
for (unsigned int h = 0; h < plain.height; h++)
    {
        for (unsigned int w = 0; w < plain.width; w++)
        {
            temp.pixels[h * temp.height / plain.height][w * temp.width / plain.width] = plain.pixels[h][w];
        }
    }
    freePixels(&plain);

    plain = temp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt (with the white pixels) is very close. The problem here is that for each pixel in the input (**plain**) there are **four** pixels in the output (**temp**) but you're only setting one of them.

To make sure you set every pixel in the output, loop over the height and width of **temp** instead of **plain** and set each pixel of **temp** to the corresponding pixel of **plain**. Something like this should work:

```
void imageEnlarge(Image *pic)
{
    temp.height = plain.height * 2;
    temp.width = plain.width * 2;

    temp.pixels = (Pixel**)malloc(sizeof(Pixel*) * temp.height);
    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < temp.height; h++)
    {
        temp.pixels[h] = (Pixel*)malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * temp.width);
    }

    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < temp.height; h++)
    {
        for (unsigned int w = 0; w < temp.width; w++)
        {
            temp.pixels[h][w] = plain.pixels[h * plain.height / temp.height][w * plain.width / temp.width];
        }
    }

    freePixels(&plain);
    plain = temp;
}
```

This should also work if you use scaling factors other than 2.

Comment: Bless you, kind sir!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @GeorgieCake - StackOverflow is usually reluctant to help with homework, but your question was clear, contained sufficient and relevant code samples, and demonstrated that you'd put in a solid effort to get this far. Keep up the good work!